# What is the simplest way, to prevent route in my web application?

Tags: security, authentication, url, web-applications, routes

I have an application, with a simple editor page. I want to prevent it from users, and i don't think authentication is the simplest way.
Of course security is important, but i have no users, just one 'key' for access this route.
I have an idea to use a very long URL, something like:

> localhost:3000/very_long_random_url_with_numbers_and_letters123XEa...

But my knowledge in back-end is so pure.
Can I use this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution is not recommended, while it does serve your purpose to some extent, it has two significant drawback:

1. The URL itself is the authentication, in plain text, meaning it is (a) prone to shoulder surfing, (b) the password is stored in browser history.
2. Since the password is written in source code, therefore anyone get hold of the source code has full access by accessing that URL.

You can actually do authentication without full on authentication stuff. One is through session and another through basic authentication.

For basic authentication, you can utilize Apache / nginx to set it up.

For session, the key is storing **hashed password** in source code, and when user visits the sensitive page, you simply do:

```
if session.isAuthed
    show sensitive page
else if is doing login
    check username and hased password
else
    show login form
endif
```